# how to get HTML direction property as a alert (RTL)

Tags: javascript, html

I am working rtl right to left direction.  I want to know how to get dir value in alert using javascript.

Here is my html code

```
<html dir="rtl">
</html>
```

Here is my javascript code

```
alert(document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]);
```

I am not getting the alert as dir ="rtl".

Based on the direction I have to do some condition checking. Instead of attribute is there any way please help me

Please help me how to get that tag name.

Regards
M

Comment: Have you tried `getAttibute`? Something like.. `document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].getAttribute('dir')`

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for the reply. Here is what i Did

```
if (document.dir == "rtl"){
 function name()
}else{
function name1()
}
```

Regards
Mahadevan

Answer (score 6):

This snippet will get data directly from html element

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].getAttribute("dir");
```

Comment: hi

Based on the direction I have to do some condition checking. if it was rtl do something else do something. Instead of attribute is there any way please help me

Comment: use jquery that is much better

Answer (score 1):

you can get this  more easily from the attributes of the document
[Document.dir](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/dir)

```
var direction;
(document.dir !=undefined)? direction =document.dir : direction =document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].getAttribute("dir");

if (direction=="rtl") {
//do something
}
else {
//do something else
}
```

Comment: hi

Based on the direction I have to do some condition checking. if it was rtl do something else do something. Instead of attribute is there any way please help me